# How to use customized methods in application.controller.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie in rails and ruby. I'm so confused by some conventions in rails~

I wrote a method like this:

```
def show_session_counter?
  if session[:counter] && session[:counter] > 4
  end
end
```

... And want to use the method in application.html.erb like this:

```
<% if show_session_counter? %>
      <li><a href="#"><%= pluralize session[:counter], "time" %></a></li>
<% end %>
```

First, I tried to put the method in application.controller.rb because I thought the method will be used in application.html.erb. I tried to put it as a normal method and as a private one. Neither work.

Then I put the method in the application_helper.rb and it works.

So my questions is: why the first way doesn't work? Is there any "rails convention" here?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put method inside your controller and want to use it in view, you need to declare it as `helper_method`.

```
helper_method :show_session_counter?

def show_session_counter?
  if session[:counter] && session[:counter] > 4
  end
end
```

Comment: Expanding @Mikhail's answer for your second question. The general rails convention here is that if you need it in your controllers, it should go in there with `helper_method`. If it is only for use in views (HTML generation, custom link settings, etc), then it should be in the helper